# how to have the color of the windows theme MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui, maui-windows

I want the main button to be of a color derived from the windows theme. for example if the windows theme is red my buttons are the same color
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UISettings Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22000#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UISettings_ColorValuesChanged) could be used to get current system color in windows platform , the point is how to convert `Windows.UI.Color` to `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color` .

##### Sample code

```java
#if WINDOWS
    var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
    var color = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);

    //change button color with system theme color
    button.BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.Parse(color.ToString());
#endif
```

---

And if you want to change the color dynamically  according to system theme, take a look at [Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes#react-to-theme-changes) event  ,it is used to to detect the change of system theme .

**Notice:** The following event is only triggered when switching between light/dark theme .

##### Sample code

```java
Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, a) =>
{
#if WINDOWS
    var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
    var color = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);

    //change button color with system theme color
    button.BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.Parse(color.ToString());
#endif
};
```

Comment: thank you but where should I put this code.

Comment: Place it in class constructor of MainPage .